# Suppose 7 people are sitting at a round table. If three people are selecting at random, find the probability that at least two of then are together.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

First we find the probability that all three sit together. The string method can be used for this. So
$$P(3)=\frac{4! 3!}{6!} =\frac 15$$

Now for finding probability that two people are together and one of them of is separate. I selected any two people out of the $3$ selected people and string them. Then number of ways to do that should be
$\binom{3}{2} 2!$

Now if this string is at any one position, then only $4$ positions are left to seat the third person. So number of ways should be $\binom{4}{1} 4!$

But multiplying all this gives a value more than 6!, which shouldn’t happen. What am I doing wrong?

I also though about using complementary method, but I didn’t know how to apply it for the circular permutation. So can I get a hint on that too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working and my answer is considering the question that if $7$ people are randomly seated on a round table, what is the probability that at least $2$ of $3$ *given* people seat together.   See my edit for the other answer.

In the second case, we can choose two out of three people from the first group and seat them together. Number of ways to do that is $\displaystyle \small \binom 32 2! \ $.

We then have the second group seat in $4!$ ways. That gives us $5$ places in between them (two being together and hence no place between them) to seat the last person. But the last person cannot be with the rest two from first group and therefore cannot occupy $2$ of those $5$ places (to the left of two from the first group seated together or to the right of them).

So toal number of ways to seat them in the second case $ = \displaystyle \small 2! \cdot \binom 32 \cdot 3 \cdot 4!$

Adding first and second case and dividing by $6!$ gives us desired probability of $ \ \displaystyle \small \frac{4}{5}$.

---

Alternatively, probability that none of the people from the first group of three are seated together,

$ = \displaystyle \small 3! \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \ / \ 6! =   \frac{1}{5}$

Explanation for numerator: we first seat second group in $3!$ ways and then we seat the first group in $3$ out of the $4$ places.

That leads to probability of $ \ \displaystyle \small \frac{4}{5}$ that at least two of them are seated together.

---

EDIT: If the interpretation is that of $7$ seated people on a round table, if we pick any $3$ randomly, what is the probability that at least two of them were seated together, the working will be as below.

Total number of ways to pick $3$ people $ = \displaystyle \small {7 \choose 3} = 35$.

case $1$: Exactly two are seated together. There are $7$ ways to pick two people seated together. As third person is not neighbor with the first two, he or she can be chosen from $3$ non-neighbors.

case $2$: All three are seated together. There are $7$ ways to pick $3$ people seated together.

So desired probability $ = \displaystyle \small \frac{3 \cdot 7 + 7}{35} = \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, Aditya.

Comment: In the second answer, why didn’t you first select three people using $\binom 73$ before finding the arrangements?

Comment: Aditya - I am going by the interpretation that we are finding it for $3$ given people. If you think of it, both answers assume the same. It says $3$ people are randomly selecting. The other interpretation of the question could be that they are randomly selected. That is different working.

Comment: Please see my EDIT that includes working for both interpretations.

Comment: Why did we get the same answer for both interpretations?

Comment: Yes even if we took a different number of people, say $6$ instead of $7$ around the table, both interpretations should give the same answer. When we select $3$ random people out of $7$ on a round table, it does count all possible seat selections where $2$ seats are together and where $3$ seats are together. For $3$ given people when we are arranging in such a way that two are together or three are together, we are counting all seat selections in the second answer but we are also arranging them. So while I see why they may be giving same answers, I have not worked it out completely.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, one of the $3$ to be chosen (or choosing seats) can be $A$ at the "head" of the table, and we can choose the remaining two in $\binom62  = 15$ unrestricted ways

If we linearize the table, it, it would look like $\require{cancel}\mathbf A \,\xcancel{:}\, \circ\, \uparrow \circ\, \uparrow\circ\, \uparrow\circ\,\xcancel{:}\,\mathbf A$
with crosses giving barred positions, and uparrows giving allowed  "apart" positions  for the other $2$ to be chosen as $\binom32 = 3$

Thus P(at least two chosen are adjacent) $= 1- \frac3{15} = \frac 45$

Answer (score 1):

Once the first person has been chosen, there are only three ways to choose the remaining two people out of 15 possibilities. This is because we need two single gaps and one double gap, and the double gap can be in one of three places.

Comment: Why do you need a double gap

Comment: @Aditya: because there are seven seats but only three people.

Comment: Yeah it’s a problem I faced while drawing the arrangement. I am not able to understand the complete significance of the double gaps though